# adding .php extension if not exist

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have the below rewrite but I want to replace the URL without extension .php if the user types the URL with .php at last, how can I revise the below rewrite script?

```
# /m/yyy rule
RewriteRule ^m/([\w-]+)/?$ merchants/$1/index.php [L,NC]
# /m/yyy/abc rule
RewriteRule ^m/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ merchants/$1/$2.php [L,NC]
# /m/yyy/abc/ rule
RewriteRule ^m/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/$ merchants/$1/$2/index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Can you add few examples

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please have your .htaccess file with following Rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
# metchants/yyy/index.php to redirect /m/yyy rule
RewriteRule ^merchants/([\w-]+)/index\.php/?$ m/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
# merchants/yyy/abc.php to redirect /m/yyy/abc rule
RewriteRule ^merchants/([\w-]+)([\w-]+)\.php/?$ m/$1/$2 [R=301,L,NC]
# merchants/yyy/xyz/abc.php to redirect /m/yyy/xyz/abc rule
RewriteRule ^merchants/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/index\.php/?$ m/$1/$2 [R=301,L,NC]

# To handle /m/yyy/index.php rewrite rule.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^m/([\w-]+)/?$ merchants/$1/index.php [QSA,L,NC]

# To handle /m/yyy/abc/index.php rewrite rule.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^m/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ merchants/$1/$2.php [QSA,L,NC]

# To handle /m/yyy/xyz/abc/index.php rewrite rule.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^m/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/$ merchants/$1/$2/index.php [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: @Kelvin, could you please do let me know if this has worked for you? Thank you.